# child class is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo()

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an arraylist with collections.sort, and I am recieving this error. BasicCard class is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Card).

```
   public class BasicCard extends Card implements Comparable<Card> 

   // inside java button method
   List<Card> valueList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Card c : cards) {
        valueList.add(c);
    }

    Collections.sort(valueList);
```

For loop is copying existing card objects into new array

Comment: `implements Comparable<Card>`. If you implement an interface, you have to implement the abstract methods of that interface. Does `BasicCard` have a `public int compareTo(Card other)` method?

Comment: My sub classes do not contain the compareTo method

Comment: And that is the problem.

Comment: In any case, your sort sees a list of `Card`, not a list of `BasicCard`. This means `Card` should implement the `Comparable` interface, not `BasicCard`.